# How to use Snackbar in RecyclerView adapter

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-snackbar

When trying to use a Snackbar for my RecyclerView adapter the errors returned don't seem to be resolvable. Which view should I be using in this situation? How can I use a string resource if it appears as an unresolved reference?

**Adapter code**

```
class MyAdapter(
    private val mCtx: Context,
    var myList: MutableList<Item>,
) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>(), Filterable {
    private val myListFull = myList.toMutableList()


val mSnackbar = Snackbar.make(
        requireView(),
        getString(R.string.my_message),
        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE
)

    private val companyFilter = object : Filter() {
        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            val filteredList = ArrayList<Item>()

            if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                filteredList.addAll(myListFull)
            } else {
                val filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim { it <= ' ' }

                for (item in myListFull) {
                    if (item.Name.toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)
                    ) {
                        filteredList.add(item)
                    }
                }
            }

            val results = FilterResults()
            results.values = filteredList
            return results
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults?) {
            myList.clear()
            myList.addAll(results!!.values as List<Item>)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun String.matchesIgnoreCase(otherString: String): Boolean {
        return this.toLowerCase().contains(otherString.trim().toLowerCase())
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    .ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title)
        var tvSubtitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return myList.size
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return companyFilter
    }
}
```

Comment: The view should be root view of component . So provide a callback to component fragment or activity and show the Snackbar there.

Comment: @ADM `Unresolved reference: 'requireActivity'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
val mSnackbar = Snackbar.make((mCtx as Activity).findViewById(android.R.id.content), mCtx.getString(R.string.xxx), Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
```

Comment: `Unresolved reference: 'requireActivity' and 'getString'`

Comment: @Swarthy46 That's weird, it works in my case. Try to rebuild the project?

Comment: This is being used in an adapter, not a fragment.